# MATLAB sort function yields tampered results

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, vector

I have a vector of 126 elements which is *usually* correctly sorted; however, I always sort it to make sure everything is okay. 
 
The problem is that: when the array is already sorted, performing a sort would destroy the original values of the array. 
 
 
I attached the array in a csv file and executed the script below, where I insert the vector in the first column of 'a' then sort it in the second then check for any differences in the third column.

```
a = csvread('a.csv')
a(:,2)=sort(a(:,1))
a(:,3)=a(:,2)-a(:,1)
result=sum(a(:,3).^2)
```

[image]

You could easily see that the first two columns aren't identical, and the third column has some none zero values.

## Syntax for array

```
a = [17.4800
   18.6800
   19.8800
   21.0800
   22.2800
   23.4800
   24.6800
   25.8800
   27.0800
   28.2800
   29.4800
   30.6800
   46.1600
   47.3600
   48.5600
   49.7600
   50.9600
   52.1600
   53.3600
   54.5600
   55.7600
   56.9600
   58.1600
   59.3600
   74.8400
   76.0400
   77.2400
   78.4400
   79.6400
   80.8400
  103.5200
  104.7200
  105.9200
  107.1200
  108.3200
  109.5200
  110.7200
  111.9200
  113.1200
  114.3200
  115.5200
  116.7200
  132.2000
  133.4000
  134.6000
  135.8000
  137.0000
  138.2000
  139.4000
  140.6000
  141.8000
  143.0000
  144.2000
  145.4000
  165.4200
  166.6200
  167.8200
  169.0200
  170.2200
  171.4200
  172.6200
  173.8200
  175.0200
  176.2200
  177.4200
  178.6200
  179.9300
  181.1300
  182.3300
  183.5300
  184.7300
  185.9300
  187.1300
  188.3300
  189.5300
  201.3700
  202.5700
  203.7700
  204.9700
  206.1700
  207.3700
  236.1100
  237.3100
  238.5100
  239.7100
  240.9100
  242.1100
  243.3100
  244.5100
  245.7100
  246.9100
  248.1100
  249.3100
  239.8400
  241.0400
  242.2400
  276.9900
  278.1900
  279.3900
  280.5900
  281.7900
  282.9900
  284.1900
  285.3900
  286.5900
  287.7900
  288.9900
  290.1900
  277.8200
  279.0200
  280.2200
  281.4200
  282.6200
  283.8200
  285.0200
  286.2200
  287.4200
  288.6200
  289.8200
  291.0200
  291.0700
  292.2700
  293.4700
  295.6900
  296.8900
  298.0900];
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What output do you expect?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The first column is the raw data, and the second column is the sorted data.  Since the first is clearly not monotonic in this example, the difference will be non-zero.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your original vector is unfortunately **not** sorted.  Therefore, sorting this result will obviously not give you what the original vector is supposed to be as the values that were out of order will become in order.

You can check this by using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) on the read in  vector from the CSV file and seeing if there are any negative differences.  `diff` takes the difference between the (i+1)th value and the ith value and if your values are monotonically increasing, you should get positive differences all around.  We can see which locations are affected by finding values in the difference that are negative:

```
a = csvread('a.csv');
ind = find(diff(a) < 0);
```

We get:

```
>> ind

ind =

    93
   108
```

This says that locations 93 and 108 are where the **out of order starts**.  Locations 94 and 109 is where it actually happens.  Let's check out portions 90 - 110 of your vector to be sure:

```
>> a(90:110)

ans =

  245.7100  % 90
  246.9100  % 91
  248.1100  % 92
  249.3100  % 93
  239.8400  %<-------
  241.0400
  242.2400
  276.9900
  278.1900
  279.3900
  280.5900
  281.7900
  282.9900
  284.1900
  285.3900
  286.5900
  287.7900 % 106
  288.9900 % 107
  290.1900 % 108
  277.8200 % <------
  279.0200
```

As you can see, locations 93 and 108 take a dip in numerical value, and so if you tried sorting the result then taking the difference, you'll notice that locations 1 up to 93 will exhibit a difference of 0, but after location 93, that's when it becomes unequal.

I'm frankly surprised you didn't see that they're out of order because your snapshot clearly shows there's a decrease in value on the left column towards the top of the snapshot.

Therefore, either check your data to see if you have input it correctly, or modify whatever process you're working on to ensure that it can handled unsorted data.